# jQuery plugin, similar to iphone app page sliding animation

Tags: iphone, html, css, animation, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jquery plugin that navigates to other pages of a website using a sliding animation similar to some iphone apps. I tried designing this on my own but I could not get it to work.

**Here is an example of what I need:**

(on pressing the button)

[image: p1]
[image: p2]
[image]

Comment: Since nobody else is answering, I guess I'll make my comments an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at JQuery Mobile? It mimics a lot of the iPhone animations, and it will run on non-mobile browsers as well as mobile browsers.  For instance, http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html has a "Slide" transition that you can demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sencha touch, never used it personally but appears to do what you want.

Demo: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#menu/animations

Download: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

There's also JQtouch a quick google will find that (as I cant post the link because of low reputation)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm going to use jQuery mobile.